# Creating a new columns based on values from existing multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to create a new column named "condition" (which is not there initially) based on the first three columns. If the values are from cond1 then it should be 1 in my condition column and so on. Any suggestions.

```r
cond_test = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/du76g4vlfz2uaph/cond_test.csv?dl=1")
cond_test
#>   ï..cond1 cond2 cond3 condition
#> 1        2    NA    NA         1
#> 2        4    NA    NA         1
#> 3       NA     3    NA         2
#> 4       NA     5    NA         2
#> 5       NA     4    NA         2
#> 6       NA    NA     1         3
#> 7       NA    NA     4         3
#> 8       NA    NA     7         3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max.col` to get first non-NA value in each row.

```
max.col(!is.na(cond_test))
#[1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

If you have more than one non-NA value in the row you can look at `ties.method` argument in `?max.col` on how to handle ties.

---

In `dplyr` you can use `rowwise` :

```
library(dplyr)
cond_test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(condition = which.max(!is.na(c_across())))
```

Comment: ```r> max.col(!is.na(cond_test)) [1] 4 4 2 4 4 4 5 3 ``` is what I am getting. Can you please share complete code.

Comment: @RamakrishnaS I am assuming there is no `condition` column in your data as mentioned in your post. `cond_test$condition <- NULL`

Comment: I removed condition, and ran the dplyr code.  I got this error.
```r Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `condition`.
x Input `condition` can't be recycled to size 1.
i Input `condition` is `which(!is.na(c_across()))`.
i Input `condition` must be size 1, not 2.
i Did you mean: `condition = list(which(!is.na(c_across())))` ?
i The error occurred in row 1. ```

Comment: @RamakrishnaS Unlike the example shared you have rows in your data where there are more than 1 value. I have used `whcih.max` to select the 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and is working. But any elegant solutions are welcome.

```r
cond_test$condition = ifelse(!is.na(cond_test$ï..cond1), 1, 
                             ifelse(!is.na(cond_test$cond2), 2, 3))
```